# RegexFilter - how to escape dot ( . ) and filter out certain messages?

Tags: java, log4j2

I want to use RegexFilter with log4j2 and I want my filter to **filter out** all messages which contain this string `abc.def`

But this dot I want to be interpreted literally, not as a regexp symbol.
I don't find this documented.

So how do I do this?
A complete example would be more helpful because I am having troubles with the syntax.

On a side note: which symbols do I need to escape and which not?

I doubt this is the right way (syntactically):

`<RegexFilter regex=".*abc.def.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT" />`

Also, is it case sensitive or insensitive?
I don't find this documented too.

Comment: Maybe with \ or \\ ?

Comment: @DiegoRuiz Thanks, but I don't think Java programs work based on maybes :) That's why I am asking (since I don't find it in the docs). It's in an XML attribute which describes a regular expression so it's tricky, could be anything.

Comment: @DiegoRuiz actually it should be either \\ or \\\\, depending on whether the string-like regex is passed directly to the java regex engine or it's pre-processed -- I'm not familiar with `RegexFilter`

Comment: A single backslash escapes regex special characters. Since a backslash itself has to be escaped in a Java-String-Literal, you'll have to write `\\.` (as long as it's inside a string literal). If you decide to configure the regex outside a java literal (for example in a configuration file), you'll have to use a single backslash only (`\.` )

Comment: @codeflush.dev It's in a log4j.xml config file. See the XML fragment I posted. We are not talking Java literals here. I know how to escape in Java literals but this is log4j 2 XML config file.

Comment: @peter.petrov AFAIK, bashslashes don't have to be escaped in XML. That would make your XML configuration: `<RegexFilter regex=".*abc\.def.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT" />`

Comment: @codeflush.dev OK... So a single backslash is what you think I would need here?

Comment: @peter.petrov yes. That said, using `[.]` as @CKey said works too.

Comment: @codeflush.dev OK, thanks. Seems I have another issue - SMTP appender does not support RegexFilter at all. Great! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

by `[.]`, thus use

```
.*abc[.]def.*
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Have you tried this before? I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
.*abc[.]def.*
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).